# Can not catch os error with subprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, subprocess, try-except

Does anyone know if you can catch os errors in python. I am working on a script that is mapping network drives.
If the end user types the name of a path that does not exist no error shows up and that could become an issues.
I am using the subprocess module, with python version 3.6, along with the pycharm IDE.
If I map to a location that does not exist I get the following error "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found."

Lastly I have tried catching the error using OSError, Exception, and BaseException. Each one that I have used does not return any error message.

Here is an example of the script that I am running.

```
def StoreInfo():
receiving = input("Enter receiving: ")
try:
    subprocess.call(r'net use y: \\' + receiving + '\\act\\rto\\transent', shell=True) #timeout=30
except OSError:
    #print("An unexpected error:" , sys.exc_info()[0])
    print(sending+"'s path does not exit!")
```

StoreInfo()

Comment: It's because no python Excpetion is raised. "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found" - it's windows error, not python

Comment: if you use `subprocess.check_call` it should also give you the return code of the process, most exit with 0 for success and any other number to indicate various error conditions but @YaroslavSurzhikov is correct, no python error is raised by this, thats why you cannot catch it.

Answer (score 0):

> Python » Documentation [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)
>
> ```
> try: 
>     retcode = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True) 
>     if retcode < 0: 
>         print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode 
>     else: 
>         print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode 
> except OSError as e: 
>     print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
> ```